# generating the PDF in NodeJS and saving to MySql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs

i am looking to save PDF file in the mysql server, which i later send on the front end browser. I have used html-pdf but not sure if i have dont it correctly,as i am struggling on front to display the pdf file. As below i successfully create the pdf file and save locally which can be seen in the VScode snapshort below and then i use the connect.query to save the file to the database, i am not sure if i am doing it correctly. any suggestions guys please.

`Snippet` of code in NodeJS

```
app.post("/api/invoice", (req, res) => {
```

- generating `pdf` file and save locally ( i can see it is saving locally)

  ```
    pdf
    .create(pdfTemplate(customer_dataand_Itemsbought), {type:"pdf"})
    .toFile(`./${user_details.Invoice_No_latest}.pdf`, 
     function (err, res) {})
  ```
- saving in the `mySQL DB`

  ```
    connection
      .query("UPDATE users_basket 
              SET invoice_document=? 
              WHERE invoiceNo=?;",
              [`${__dirname}/${user_details.Invoice_No_latest}.pdf`, 
              user_details.Invoice_No_latest],
              function (err, results) {})}
  ```
- Selecting `data` from `DB`(it include the `pdf` file + other customer `info`) and then sending it to the browser using the API call

  ```
   connection
   .query("SELECT * FROM  users_basket 
           WHERE users_user_id=?;", 
           [user_id], 
           function (err, results) { res.json(results);}
  ```
- screenshot in the DB and can see hex under Invoice_document( after i save the pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take this as a comment:

Ive been dealing with file generation/store several years, and found that it is not good to save files into a DB. This because the more users you get, the more data you will have. And believe me, storing a file is big and expensive.

If you can GENERATE the PDF (in memory), SEND it to the FRONT and then DELETE IT (from memory) would be awesome.
But if you strongly need to save the PDF file, you can save it in a MONGO DB or store it in a fileserver and just deal with names/keys.

Comment: Thanks, tbh i am a bit new and this is the only option i  thought would be feasible. What kind of file server you suggest for file saving and if you could please guide me with example as that will help me understand Thankyou

Comment: NP.
Im not a node.js programmer. But I use JasperReport to generate PDF files from a given data (look at this: https://github.com/agmoyano/node-jasper) . I found it easy to use.

Comment: Thanks alot luisfa